# What's the difference between anaconda2/Lib/site-packages/<pkg> and anaconda2/pkgs/<pkg>?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I have the latest anaconda2 installed. I found the same packages exist in both `anaconda2/Lib/site-packages/<pkg>` and `anaconda2/pkgs/<pkg>`. What are the differences and the pkgs under which one are called in python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The packages in the `Anaconda2/Lib/site-packages` folder is where Python looks to import packages. The packages in the `Anaconda2/pkgs` folder are the packages that are downloaded and extracted by Conda when you specify an update or install. Depending on your settings, the folders in `Anaconda2/Lib/site-packages` may be symlinks or hardlinks to the equivalent folder in `Anaconda2/pkgs`, or it might be a copy. See the documentation: https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/configuration/use-condarc.html?highlight=symlink#disallow-soft-linking-allow-softlinks