# What is the difference between the 'pkgs' directory and the 'site-packages' directory? [Anaconda]

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda, site-packages

[Anaconda3, Windows]

What are the explicit differences between the directories 'site-packages' and 'pkgs' in my Anaconda3 (base python env) folder?

Additionally, I would like to know why 'pkgs' is significantly larger in size than 'site-packages.' On my disk 'pkgs' is 8.0 GB with 112,005 items while 'site-packages' is 1.9 GB with 57,580 items.

I have read the following link :
[What's the difference between anaconda2/Lib/site-packages/<pkg> and anaconda2/pkgs/<pkg>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46712259/whats-the-difference-between-anaconda2-lib-site-packages-pkg-and-anaconda2-pk)

I assume the difference to have to do with caching. Any knowledge or insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

packages in the Anaconda3/Lib/site-packages folder is where Python looks to import packages.

whereas packages in the Anaconda3/pkgs folder are the packages that are downloaded and extracted by Conda when you specify an update or install.

It all Depends on your settings, the folders in Anaconda2/Lib/site-packages may be symlinks or hardlinks to the equivalent folder in Anaconda2/pkgs, or it might be a copy.

See the [documentation](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/configuration/use-condarc.html?highlight=symlink#disallow-soft-linking-allow-softlinks) for clear picture.

Comment: So when I am programming, which directory files am I using?

Comment: site-packages/ which  is one of the places anaconda is going to look for installed packages when you try to import them.

Comment: I have less than 15 rep. I can't yet. I would if I could!